# When migrating to AWS route53 should I delete the original nameserver addresses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

After I have added the AWS delegation set to the original NS list, should I then delete the default NS set provided by the original service?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do.

As stated in step 3 [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html#Step_UpdateRegistrar), you must **replace** the old name server set with the AWS delegation set.